# How to download from letv

Tags: software-recommendation, downloads, download-manager, downloaders

I want to download videos from letv(le.com), is there any applications or tools to do it?

For example: [Films 1](http://www.le.com/ptv/vplay/26848165.html)

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

No, letv only has Windows client but no Linux client application. I tried Windows client under wine on my Ubuntu and it would not work.

If you are feeling adventurous and willing to do some dirty work, you can install genymotion android emulator and use android emulator that way. Thats how i use QQ on Linux. Its a bit of work but best alternative I could find so far. You will probably need to download the apk installer of letv client from Baidu though